# Getting this error while installing wifi driver Leoxsys in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, compiling, error-handling

````
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
November, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524.tar.gz
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/clean
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/efuse/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_ap.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_bt_mp.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_sreset.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_tdls.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_vht.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_wapi.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_wapi_sms4.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/hal_com.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/hal_com_phycfg.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/hal_intf.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/hal_phy.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/led/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/led/hal_usb_led.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_precomp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_reg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11AC.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11N.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/odm_types.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/Hal8192EReg_Odm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_BB.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_BB.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_FW.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_FW.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_MAC.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_MAC.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_RF.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalHWImg8192E_RF.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalPhyRf_8192e.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/HalPhyRf_8192e.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/odm_RegConfig8192E.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/odm_RegConfig8192E.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/odm_RTL8192E.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8192e/odm_RTL8192E.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/Hal8192EPwrSeq.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_cmd.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_dm.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_hal_init.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_mp.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_phycfg.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_rf6052.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_rxdesc.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_sreset.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/rtl8192e_xmit.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_led.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_recv.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/rtl8192eu_xmit.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/hal/rtl8192e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/autoconf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/basic_types.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/custom_gpio.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_gspi.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_pci.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_sdio.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/ethernet.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/gspi_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/gspi_ops.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/gspi_ops_linux.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/gspi_osintf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8188EPhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8188EPhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8188EPwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192EPhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192EPhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8192EPwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723APhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723APhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723BPhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723BPhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723BPwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8723PwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8812PhyCfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8812PhyReg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8812PwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/Hal8821APwrSeq.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/HalPwrSeqCmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/HalVerDef.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_com.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_com_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_com_phycfg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_com_reg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_data.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_intf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_pg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_phy.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/hal_phy_reg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/if_ether.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/ip.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/linux/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/linux/wireless.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_service_bsd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_service_ce.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_service_linux.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/osdep_service_xp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8188e_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8192e_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_bt-coexist.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_pg.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723a_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_bt-coexist.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8723b_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_dm.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_led.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8812a_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8821a_spec.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtl8821a_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ap.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_bt_mp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_sreset.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_tdls.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_vht.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_wapi.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/sta_info.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/usb_ops_linux.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/wifi.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/Kconfig
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/Makefile
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/custom_gpio_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/runwpa
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524/wlan0dhcp
rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build M=/home/r4w0rm__/Desktop/drivers wifi adapter/linux/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:670: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'wifi'.  Stop.
```none
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
Makefile:1043: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################

Edit 1: output of lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: We are starting to suspect that you do not have an rtl8192eu device.

Answer (score 1):

> generic/build M=/home/r4w0rm__/Desktop/drivers wifi adapter

It appears that there are spaces in the name. Linux and, especially 'make' is troubled by spaces. Please rename the file to something like:

```
~/Desktop/drivers_wifi_adapter
```

Then try again:

```
cd ~/Desktop/drivers_wifi_adapter/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: The pure driver will not build. It needs patching for kernel 4.4. I did that in my PPA.

Comment: Space is not the isssue. I tried with a different name and got no success.

Comment: Do you mean it still didn't compile or that it did compile but doesn't drive your device?

Comment: the driver available at the website didn't compile @chili555

Comment: Please proceed to @Pilot6's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can install this driver form a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Comment: I followed the above 3 lines of command in terminal, It completed successfully but got no result

Comment: Did you reboot after it?

Comment: What is "the same problem"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to connect my laptop to wifi using this wifi adapter but it is not showing the available networks. I tried to install the driver available at the website but failed, now i tried the method suggested by you (using ppa) but still can't go further. In windows, this adapter does work fine.

Comment: Here is the screenshot: -->>   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_h6kP2TvZb9b09MVi1oUGE3Tjg